# Center first li on one line, remaining lis on second line

Tags: css

I have an `li` of two to five elements, depending on how the page gets rendered.  I want the first to appear on one line, centered, and then the remaining ones to be centered on the following line.

```
 -----------------
|                 |
|       ONE       |
|  TWO THREE FOUR |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

I've gotten the first where I want it to be, but I can't get the ones on the second line to move.

Here's my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dkzxfcb0/

If possible, I'd like to get rid of the wrapping div entirely, but that's very low on my list of priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the parent `ul` element, and then make all the children `li` element `inline-block`. Set the first child to `display: block` to place it on a separate line.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgu5f055/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My Two-Three-Four are still left-aligned.  I must have something else blocking them.

Comment: URGH.  The other Li elements had a float: left all the way at the bottom.  Stupid CSS.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add to you li:

```
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.333%
```

and to li:nth-child(1)

```
  width: 100%;
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you are using a list for something structured more like a table?

Something like this works:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">One</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td> 
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's responsive design, so this is only for the mobile view.  It needs to be a list for larger viewports

Comment: ..this also won't work for a dynamic number of elements since `colspace="3"` is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: table;` on the `ul` and make the `li` elements `display: inline-block;`. The `li:first-child` should be a `display: block;` to push the other `li` elements down.

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkzxfcb0/3/)**

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: table;
    list-style: none;
    -moz-padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
li:first-child{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```